# time vs gettimeofday c ++

Tags: c++, time, gettimeofday

The time command returns the time elapsed in execution of a command.

If I put a "gettimeofday()" at the start of the command call (using system() ), and one at the end of the call, and take a difference, it doesn't come out the same. (its not a very small difference either)

Can anybody explain what is the exact difference between the two usages and which is the best way to time the execution of a call?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you have a long running task, `time()` is a terrible idea. It only counts seconds, whilist `gettimeofday()` can return microseconds.

Comment: Could you clarify whether `time` refers to the C library function, or the shell command? And could you give examples of the difference you're seeing?

Comment: I was actually referring to the shell command time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Unix `time` command measures the whole program execution time, including the time it takes for the system to load your binary and all its libraries, and the time it takes to clean up everything once your program is finished.

On the other hand, `gettimeofday` can only work inside your program, that is after it has finished loading (for the initial measurement), and before it is cleaned up (for the final measurement).

Which one is best? Depends on what you want to measure... ;)

Comment: Thanks!
I was hoping to find a subtle difference!

Answer (score 6):

It's all dependent on what you are timing. If you are trying to time something in *seconds*, then `time()` is probably your best bet. If you need higher resolution than that, then I would   consider `gettimeofday()`, which gives up to *microsecond* resolution (1 / 1000000th of a second).

If you need even higher resolution than that, consider using `clock()` and `CLOCKS_PER_SECOND`, just note that `clock()` is rarely an accurate description for the amount of time taken, but rather the number of CPU cycles used.

Answer (score 5):

`time()` returns time since epoch in **seconds**.

`gettimeofday():` returns:

```
struct timeval {
       time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
       suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time function has different precision. In C++11 you would use std::chrono:

```
using namespace std::chrono;

auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
/* do stuff*/
auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();

float elapsedSeconds = duration_cast<duration<float>>(end-start).count();
```